# Overflow wrap not being applied to text

Tags: html, css, angular

### Issue

I currently have a side menu that I have built using Angular and it works pretty well on my screen (4k resolution). Problem being on smaller screens the text in the menu doesn't wrap so it overflows the container div. I have tried applying `overflow-wrap: break-word;` to the text but that is not working.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

You can see the issue below:

[image: Text overflowing div]

---

### Code

**HTML of the component:**

```
<div class="sidebar animated fadeIn">
  <div class="header">
    <div style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%;">
      <img src="../../../assets/images/logo.svg" style="width:100%" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="menu-item" *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="goTo(item.path)">
    <i class="material-icons">{{item.icon}}</i>
    <h3 class="text">{{item.name}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Styling of the component:**

```
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 10%;
  background: rgba(191, 158, 69, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(191, 158, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(250, 239, 210, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0%, rgba(191, 158, 69, 1)),
    color-stop(100%, rgba(250, 239, 210, 1))
  );
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(191, 158, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(250, 239, 210, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(191, 158, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(250, 239, 210, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(191, 158, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(250, 239, 210, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(191, 158, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(250, 239, 210, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bf9e45', endColorstr='#faefd2', GradientType=0 );
  box-shadow: 5px 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
}

.spacer {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.menu-item {
  border-top: 1px solid darkgray;
  padding-left: 2em;
  height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item .text {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this property `word-break: break-all;`

```
.menu-item .text {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /*overflow-wrap: break-word;*/
  word-break: break-all;
}
```